# GROUP BY, filter and order data

Tags: apache-pig

I have data in following format

```
(id_type:chararray,id:long,date_cnt_bag:{(date:chararray,count:long)})
```

I only have 4 different ID types

```
id_type: A/B/C/D
```

I want to convert this data into following format

```
(id, date, A_count, B_count, C_count, D_count)
```

E.g.

```
A 1 {(20161209, 100),(20161208, 90),(20161207, 80)}
B 1 {(20161209, 1000),(20161208, 900),(20161207, 800)}
C 1 {(20161209, 100),(20161208, 90)}
D 1 {(20161209, 10),(20161208, 9),(20161207, 8)}
A 2 {(20161209, 100),(20161208, 90),(20161207, 80)}
B 2 {(20161209, 1000),(20161207, 800)}
C 2 {(20161209, 100),(20161208, 90),(20161207, 80)}
D 2 {(20161209, 10),(20161208, 9),(20161207, 8)}
```

The output should be as follows. Also note that I want to put 0 if the count is missing for that date.

```
1 20161209 (100 1000 100 10)
1 20161208 (90 900 90 9)
1 20161207 (80 800 0 8)
2 20161209 (100 1000 100 10)
2 20161208 (90 0 90 9)
2 20161207 (80 800 80 8)
```

I searched for possible solutions and hints. But I am not going anywhere. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
raw = LOAD '...' using PigStorage(...) as (id_type:chararray,id:long,date_cnt_bag:{(date:chararray,count:long)});

flattened = foreach raw generate id_type, id, flatten(date_cnt_bag);

final = foreach (group flattened by (id, date)) {
  A_count_g = filter flattened by id_type == 'A';
  A_count = foreach A_count_g generate count as a_cnt;
  ... same for all 4 ...
  generate
    group.id,
    group.date,
    flatten(A_count) 
  ;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vinay Here is the script where you will get 0 and not miss data for null info rows, (2,20161208,90,0,90,9) If data is not validated for Empty row will be lost.

```
raw = LOAD '/user/data/grp_ABCD.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (id_type:chararray,id:long,date_cnt_bag:{(date:chararray,count:long)});

flattened = foreach raw generate id_type, id, flatten(date_cnt_bag);

final = foreach (group flattened by (id, date)) {
  A_count_g = filter flattened by id_type == 'A';
  A_count = foreach A_count_g generate count  as a_cnt;
  B_count_g = filter flattened by id_type == 'B';
  B_count = foreach B_count_g generate count  as b_cnt;      
  C_count_g = filter flattened by id_type == 'C';
  C_count = foreach C_count_g generate count as c_cnt;  
  D_count_g = filter flattened by id_type == 'D';
  D_count = foreach D_count_g generate count as d_cnt;

  generate
    group.id,
    group.date,
    flatten((IsEmpty(A_count)  ?  {((long)0)} : A_count )),    
    flatten((IsEmpty(B_count)  ?  {((long)0)} : B_count )),
    flatten((IsEmpty(C_count)  ?  {((long)0)} : C_count )),
    flatten((IsEmpty(D_count)  ?  {((long)0)} : D_count ))
  ;
};
```

Comment: Your load statement itself is incorrect.The data is comma separated and you are using tab '\t' as the delimiter.

Comment: If regular fields and bag fields have same delimiter it will not work, I have used '/t'for regular and ',' for bag., Hope this helped